# How to create objects that have relationships when using Backand BaaS?

Tags: angularjs, one-to-many, backand

I am using Backand BaaS for my ionic app. My model consists of two tables:
1. Users
2. Trips

A one-to-many relationship has been established between 'Users' and 'Trips'.

'Users' has a collection field that is a collection of 'Trips' and 'Trips' has a owner field that is an object of 'Users'.

What is the correct way to create an object so that upon creating I am assigning the correct owner ('Users' object) to 'Trips' collection field ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When POSTing a new Trip use this for the Trip Object

```
{
tripName:"asdf"
owner:1
}
```

In the users object it will look like this

```
{
id:1
fName:"david"
trips:[{__metadata: {id: 1}, tripName: "asdf"}]
}
```

Comment: how is that then represented on the user objects collection of 'users'?

Comment: I've edite my answer to show both sides of the relation